In Buddhism, why care about future selves?
This pertains to any philosophies regarding rebirth. But as it pertains to Buddhism, there is the concept of "atman", specifcally I am focused on "anatta", the idea no-self.
If only ~psychomaterial is connected between lives, possible echos of memories from previous lives but no memories transferred, and yet no self, then why care about future rebirths?

I'm going to offer a deep reading of the notion of rebirth that I think answers this question, but I want to be clear that this position is not typical of what you'll hear in Buddhist discussions, and might even confound some Buddhists outright. Don't take what I say as canon…
That aside, I think it's important to recognize that the notion of rebirth isn't about the self; it's a function of karma. Metaphysically speaking, whenever we take action we create something like a resonant wav which is naturally cyclical, constantly recreating itself. The self as we know it is merely the crest of a wave, built up over a lifetime of action. That wave energy eventually collapses and cycles through, creating a new wave with all the tendencies of momentum and trajectory that the last wave had. It makes a new crest, which is a new self, which is much like the old self.
That's rebirth.
It's a bit like the old movie Groundhog Day, a weird kind of time loop where we keep waking up where we were the last time, and the only way out is to change who we are and what we do. With the caveat, of course, that there's no way to know if the Phil Connors (Bill Murray's character) who wakes up in one cycle is ontologically the  Phil Connors who went to sleep in the last cycle.
So the question isn't really whether we care about our future selves. The question is whether we want to go through it all again. What we put into or pull out of the world doesn't cease moving at our death. It cycles, so that someone with all our tendencies — good ones, odd ones, miserable ones, perverse ones — will appear: someone who thinks it's 'me' just as you and I think we're 'me', and tends to think and act the way our 'me' does. If you were forced to make a mental and physical clone of yourself, would you want it to be exactly like you in every way and live your life as you did, or would you want it to be better and have a better life? Because that's essentially the nature of karma, recreating what has been created.

All school of Buddhism make two claims:

The doctrine of transmigration (saṃsāra)

The doctrine of emptiness (śūnyatā)



The doctrine of transmigration based on karma is the general
doctrine of nearly all old Indian schools. The historical Buddha
took it from the tradition without further questioning.
The
historical roots of this doctrine go back to the time of the Vedic
Brahmanas. Possibly the idea was developed in analogy to the cycle
of the year as observed in agriculture. And it combined with a
principle of retributive justice.
Saṃsāra was considered a law of
nature. It was considered painful. Different school proposed
different methods to end Saṃsāra. Its end was named nirvāṇa (= blown
out).

The doctrine of emptiness is a specific Buddhist doctrine. It
objects to the Vedic teaching of ātman (self), the essence of the
person. Ātman was never clearly identified. Emptiness emphasizes the
absence of any permanence in time.

Both doctrines object each other: If there is no individual
permanence between the different phases of saṃsāra, in particular no
memory, how can there be a continuity between the phases?
I think
this objection meets with your question. IMO the question has never been
answered in a convincing way. It seems that this question is
neglected most often in Buddhist teachings.


Hence I recommend to post your question also on buddhism.stackexchange.com in order to hear first-hand the opinion of Buddhist monks and laymen.

I think youre mixing up shunyaya with anatta (an-atma in Sanskrit). Rest fine — There is a deep contradiction

Ok done. Pls see

@Rushi You paint with three brushstrokes the Christian religion, Buddhism and Vedanta. But why do I mix up up in your eyes shunyata with anatta?

Anatma is stated as an ontological fact, Shunyata is a spiritual experience. I guess its more a category error than a factual error to use it as you do

Every significant religion has its own specific fundamental flaw.  The easiest way to pinpoint it is to ask the major detractors, atheists etc of that religion what is their finding of that flaw.
So for example in Christianity it's called Theodicy : If God is supremely good, why evil, sin, hell etc.?
In Buddhism it's the mismatch between dukha and anatta. If atma (self) is a fake then obviously so is the dukha that it suffers. Why worry about it?
To me this kind of contradiction peaks in Hinduism. The central doctrine of Vedanta is the trio:

Brahman is (the only) reality
Jagat (world) is unreal
Jagat is Brahman only

Heh!
Then why do Vedanta texts spend 80-90% of their volume on maya (unreality)?
So the atheists and other detractors feel pleased and gloat and mock What a pack of nonsense we have uncovered!
They scoff but don't see they are scoffing at themselves!  Religions are clear mirrors for our own faults, some of which are the deep contradictions embedded into our psyche.

It is the Christian's experience that God/Christ is good and he is sinful
It is the Buddhist experience that he suffers and yet meditation reveals that consciousness is a stream without a center
It is the Hindu experience that the ego is a fake that causes hallucinations. And yet, this non existent ego rules all!

So you can rest pretty that you've uncovered nonsense in these great and revered systems.
Or you can be piqued at what they show you in the mirror. And then try to figure a way out.
Personal Note
To me these are all stories; they may point to something important but they're all ultimately stories. So:

Buddha says the world is suffering
Genesis says God saw the world and it was good
The Vedas say that happiness — ananda — is at the foundation of every being
Ramana Maharshi calls all human activities seshtai — frolic

I see truth in all these, but dont own any of them as my truth.
You can check for yourself with an open mind...

The seeming opposition between Hinduism and Buddhism
 Added later to a query of Jo Wehler
In Buddhism, the principal principle is anatta — there is no self.
Vedanta by contrast could be called atma-ism!
The contradiction should be obvious! But is there teally any?
The essential viewpoint of Buddhism is empiricist; whereas Vedanta is rationalist. What Buddhists call atma, Hindus call ahankar (ego) — a faux entity.
Conversely, what Hindus call sakshatkar, self realization, Buddhists call shunyata emptiness

Ad Vedanta: I agree that two key-terms of Vedanta are ātman and brahman.  The question is: How to identify the two and how do they relate to each other? - Ad Samkhya: ahaṃkāra (= I-making) is one of the keyterms in the anthropology of Hindu Samkhya. But I do not know your Sanskrit term sakshatkar. - Ad Buddhism: Where do Buddhist apply the term ātman in a positive sense?  IMO they use it only in the negative sense: śūnyatā = an-ātman. But that’s exactly the point of our specific discussion. - I am curious why your answer has been downvoted.

@JoWehler साक्षात thence साक्षात्कार  ie literally to preceive thence make the perception self evident, almost always translated as realization. Usually used as आत्मा  साक्षात्कार self realization. Which of course needs to taken in the non dual context of Vedanta where आत्मा = ब्रह्म is a mahavakya or axiom

Are you sure that साक्षात्कार  is usually used as आत्मा साक्षात्कार ? According to the dictionary साक्षात्कार = intuitive perception, realization.

@JoWehler Well obviously I imply a spiritual discourse. In the worldly domain it has other meanings like interview — you manifest physically to the interviewer, also witness in courts of law साक्षी etc. Within spirituality, if we assume India we assume advaita vedanta. So आत्मा is implicitly परमात्मा — literally supreme self, colloquially God. Within advaita vedanta, definitionally God realization = self realization

One of the central teachings in Buddhism is “no self”, so the idea of worrying about even a self in the present moment, let alone in the future or past, is right out from the start. In general the structure of consciousness is such that it does not actually require the “self” and in a certain way the notion of a completely-independent selfhood is an illusion, so it can’t be carried over since it isn’t here in the first place; it is a form of ignorance to imagine that you are a separate suffering subjectivity distinct from the universe.
Now there is another dimension of selfhood, which is related to individuality and avoiding group delusions, which requires the “self selfing the self” or getting in touch with a “true self” beyond the false self. But the idea is this true self is precisely detached from particular interests other than the genuine well-being of all sentient beings. It seems to me the most basic teaching of Buddhism is to remember, to return to a magnanimous and nurturing self: a self which is not formed from separation and confusion but rather from universal love. This is the self of no self which is capable of healing and transforming our karma or wounded parts.
In any case — to my mind, there is no self to be reborn in the first place — so it seems to me the teaching must be getting at something else. Perhaps enough of a hint here might be that one can be concerned with our past and future lives — dharma ancestors and descendants… — without being concerned with some essential property or clinging to fixed self (projecting an illusory unchanging reflexive identity on our experience).

"worrying about" Like, the practice of Buddhism is worrying about how we misinterpret the self, & through the chain of dependent origination cause suffering. Abandoning the Three Heaps is surely a kind of 'worrying about' what the self does.

I believe this answer skirts around the core of the question. There are Buddhist teachings which focus on how you (as an individual) can transcend samsara, and the role of karma in your path to enlightenment in your future lives. For those Buddhists which subscribe to that viewpoint, if self is an illusion, why focus on personal enlightenment or personal rebirth? Why isn't the emphasis rather on personal actions which lead to nirvana more generally? If the world in general gets closer to breaking the cycle of suffering, why should it matter how your actions change "your" next reincarnations?
